# Como mostrar o resultado do calculo de duas colunas no mysql usando uma trigger?

Tags: mysql

Pessoas, preciso fazer o seguinte... 
Preciso calcular as informações da coluna A com a da coluna B, e mostrar o resultado (total), na coluna C. 
Minha coluna A tem o nome de aulas, e é do tipo INT 
Minha coluna B tem o nome de valor, e é do tipo DECIMAL(9,2) 
Minha coluna C tem o nome de total, e é do tipo DECIMAL(9,2), e está vazia 
Tirando a coluna C, as outras duas ja tem dados armazenados... 
Usando uma trigger, como faço para "atualizar" esta coluna C para que automaticamente ela preencha com o calculo das outras duas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5PT.png)

Ja tentei fazer o seguinte...

```
CREATE TRIGGER calcula_total_cursos AFTER UPDATE
    ON cursos
    FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.total = (NEW.aulas + NEW.valor);
```

Neste caso ele dá um erro que é: "Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

Eu usei um select para dar um exemplo de como queria que ficasse:

```
SELECT c.nome Nome,
   c.descricao Descrição,
   c.aulas Aulas,
   c.valor Valor,
   (c.aulas * c.valor) Total
   FROM cursos c;
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ks9D.png)

Comment: Talvez seja melhor uma coluna virtual .... https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar o resultado do cálculo de duas colunas em uma tabela do MySQL usando uma trigger, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

Crie uma nova coluna na tabela para armazenar o resultado do cálculo. Por exemplo, se você deseja calcular a soma de duas colunas "coluna1" e "coluna2", crie uma nova coluna chamada "soma_colunas".

```
ALTER TABLE minha_tabela ADD soma_colunas INT;
```

Crie uma trigger para atualizar a nova coluna sempre que houver uma inserção ou atualização nas colunas "coluna1" e "coluna2". A trigger deve calcular a soma das duas colunas e armazenar o resultado na nova coluna "soma_colunas".

```
CREATE TRIGGER minha_trigger AFTER INSERT ON minha_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE minha_tabela SET soma_colunas = coluna1 + coluna2 WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER minha_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON minha_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE minha_tabela SET soma_colunas = coluna1 + coluna2 WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Agora, sempre que uma nova linha for inserida ou uma linha existente for atualizada na tabela, a trigger irá calcular a soma das colunas "coluna1" e "coluna2" e armazenar o resultado na nova coluna "soma_colunas".

```
INSERT INTO minha_tabela (coluna1, coluna2) VALUES (10, 20);

UPDATE minha_tabela SET coluna1 = 30 WHERE id = 1;
```

Você pode verificar o resultado do cálculo executando uma consulta SELECT na tabela.

```
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, soma_colunas FROM minha_tabela;
```

Espero que isso ajude! Note que este exemplo foi baseado em uma tabela com a coluna "id" sendo utilizada como chave primária. Se a tabela não possui uma chave primária, você precisará adaptar a trigger para usar outra coluna que identifique unicamente cada linha na tabela.